# How do you use PowerShell CIM to get and/or set registry values on a remote computer?

Tags: powershell, registry, remote-access

How do you use a PowerShell CIM command to get and/or set registry values on a remote computer?  I have verified that the New-CimSession connected properly but I can't find the command(s) to get or set registry values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `Invoke-CimMethod` to invoke the proper method of the [`StdRegProv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393664.aspx) WMI class for that, e.g. [like this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/02/02/registry-cmdlets-working-with-the-registry/):

```
$computer = 'remotehost'
$hive     = [uint32]'0x80000002'  # HKLM
$subkey   = 'SOFTWARE\Foo'
$value    = 'bar'
$data     = 'baz'

Invoke-CimMethod -Computer $computer -Namespace 'root/cimv2' -Class 'StdRegProv' -MethodName 'SetStringValue' -Arguments @{
    'hDefKey'     = $hive
    'sSubKeyName' = $subkey
    'sValueName'  = $value
    'sValue'      = $data
}
```

However, instead of CIM or WMI I would recommend using the proper [.Net API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey_methods.aspx):

```
$computer = 'remotehost'
$hive     = 'LocalMachine'  # HKLM
$subkey   = 'SOFTWARE\Foo'
$value    = 'bar'
$data     = 'baz'

$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($hive, $computer)
$key = $reg.OpenSubKey($subkey, $true)
$key.SetValue($value, $data, 'String')
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do it over a PSsession

```
$RemoteComputer = New-PSsession -Computer CompNamehere

Invoke-Command -Computer $RemoteComputer -ScriptBlock {Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\registrypath}
```

This will show examples

```
Get-Help Set-ItemProperty -Full
```

Comment: I tried your solution but my remote connections require the DCOM protocol, thus CIM commands.

Comment: This might be of help https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/02/02/registry-cmdlets-working-with-the-registry/